# LocalScroll works perfect in Firefox, IE, but not Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

UPDATE: works fine in Firefox, IE7 and Chrome, but not Safari. Now I'm really confused.

Only rarely do I have issues with Safari, but this is quite interesting.

It's just a cookie cutter [LocalScroll](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/) call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#politician_filter').click(
  function() {
   $("#all-people ul").fadeOut(500).filter("#politicians").fadeIn(500)
   return false;
  }
 )
 $('#entertainer_filter').click(
  function() {
   $("#all-people ul").fadeOut(500).filter("#entertainers").fadeIn(500)
   return false;
  }
 )
 $('#all_filter').click(
  function() {
   $("#all-people ul").fadeOut(500).filter("#all-people ul").fadeIn(500)
   return false;
  }
 )
 $('#events-nav').localScroll();
});


</script>
```

That is the entirety of the script, but only the last line there is important. Thought I would post it all in case you see any issues that might be causing it.

As I said in the title, LocalScroll works perfect in Firefox, and even IE7, but not Safari. Trying to get a hold of a Chrome installation (Currently at work...), to test if it's webkit-wide.

Thanks!

Judson

Comment: If you had actually hosted an example of the issue, I would have tested in all major browsers for you. Now I'm ignoring the issue completely.

Comment: I tried the demo on the plugin site - appears to work fine in Safari.  Is there some specific aspect that isn't working? or can you post a link to a demo that we can test/inspect?

Answer (score 1):

I've read that there are issues with LOCAL files in Safari, but that localscroll will actually work once your files are uploaded to the server. I have not tested this though.